# A question about integrals and numerical integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I have a function $f(r)=(1+r/2)^{(-5/r)}-1/r$ and I need to solve the integral of its reciprocal. However, I failed. Is there a way to get the analytical formula of this integral? If it is possible to have to integrate numerically, I hope that the result of numerical integration can be called in other formulas. So how can this be achieved? Below is my attempt code:

```
f[r_] = (1 + r/2)^(-5/r) - 1/r;
Integrate[1/f[r], r]
```

Think for your help and answer.

Comment: For numerical integration e.g., `NIntegrate[1/f[r], {r, -2, 2}]`. You have to specify the limits of integration. Also see: `Plot[1/f[r], {r, -5, 20}, Exclusions -> None]`

Comment: Mathematica failed , because math fails in your case.

Comment: @Syed Actually, I know the usage format of the numerical integration function. My problem now is that I need an analytical result for this integral so that I can proceed to the next calculation. For example, I can plot rs[r] and solve for the inverse. Now, the result of my test is that no analytical solution can be obtained. However, numerical integration is a numerical value, and I cannot draw graphs and inverse function solutions. If possible, I would like to get an analytical expression, which facilitates further calculations and needs, whether by integration or numerical integration.

Comment: As [Google reports](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=numerical+integrals&ei=ZsEiZNnnH8mLgQaz9byoCQ&ved=0ahUKEwjZsrqctf79AhXJRcAKHbM6D5UQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=numerical+integrals&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzIHCAAQgAQQEzIICAAQBxAeEBMyCggAEAcQHhAKEBMyCAgAEAcQHhATMggIABAHEB4QEzIICAAQBxAeEBMyCAgAEAcQHhATMggIABAHEB4QEzIICAAQBxAeEBMyCAgAEAcQHhATOgoIABBHENYEELADOgYIABAHEB46CAgAEAcQHhAKSgQIQRgAUOIWWOYfYIYlaAFwAXgAgAH6AogB-wOSAQcwLjEuMC4xmAEAoAEByAEIwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz-serp), "numerical integrals" is a non-standard notion. Because of this reason the title is edited by me.

Comment: Relevant [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/760721/are-discontinuous-functions-integrable-and-integral-of-every-continuous-functio#:~:text=It's%20not%20integrable!,would%20say%20this%20is%20integrable.) at the MathSE. Perhaps you want to start a new question at the MathSE?

Comment: If you are interested only in a specific range of `r`, the problem is potentially much more tractable.  For example, over the range `-1<r<1` the function is well behaved.  Over this range, I think you would be able to get a good polynomial approximation (which would integrate accurately).

Comment: @mikado This is where my headaches come from. My expectation is that the range of $r$ is between $-500$ and $500$. There is nothing I can do.

Comment: I think you are trying to integrate over a variety of intervals in the range you mention.  One issue is that you have a first order pole close to 4.  Do your intervals span this pole? Do you want to take the principal value?

Comment: @mikado I have a simple model here, $f(r)=1-1/r$. Its inverse is interrupted at 1. But it still performs the integral operation. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: With `f[r_] = 1 - 1/r`, if I try `Integrate[1/f[r], {r, 0, 2}]`, Mathematica says that it doesn't converge

Comment: @mikado It is true. However, for me, the result of the definite integral is a definite value, which is not helpful. The indefinite integral of $f(r)$, which allows me to do further calculations. For example, it is possible to solve the inverse function of $f(r)$ at any position. Actually, the indefinite integral of $1/f(r)=1(1-1/r)$ can be calculated. The result of this indefinite integral is what I need. So I'm trying to figure out why, which might help me with our original question.